# how to develop a scientific calculator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have made a simple calculator for iPhone.

Now I'm trying to create a scientific one. I have searched a lot over the internet and here on how to go about it. But could find anything substantial. Most of them are about making a simple calculator.

It will be of great help if you guys could direct me in the right direction like:
1. what approach should i take?
2. is there any helpful tutorial/blog?
3. things i should be learning in obj-c for making scientific calculator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Searching a lot I found: http://thomasokken.com/free42/

Comment: This is a pretty vague and open-ended question. I recommend you ask something more specific. What part are you having trouble with? This doesn't seem too hard - just apply the proper function to the value currently displayed.

Comment: @user1118321 what i am having trouble is how to go about evaluating something like "2+3/2*4" to give actual result 8, not 10 as a simple calculator evaluates.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl thanks! i am going through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. A "simple" scientific calculator, like Apple's could be done by expanding what you already have. Just add additional functions, like sine, cosine, square root, power. Look at how Apple's calculator works.

If you want to develop something that can interpret longer terms like `sin(123)+sqrt(log(12))` you have to take an other approach. You have to transform the term to [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (aka. postfix notation) first and then solve it step by step.