# How to find out antilog

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am trying to calculate the antilog. But it does not give me the desired result.
please help me..

```
   double number=74.5;
   double logOfNumber=log10(number);
   double antilog = pow(10, logOfNumber) ;
   NSLog(@"%lf",antilog);
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101524/how-to-develop-a-scientific-calculator?rq=1

Comment: [calculating antilog of a number](http://programsimply.blogspot.in/2011/03/program-22-calculating-antilog-of.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857749/how-to-find-out-anti-log-in-objective-c

Comment: Please google once before asking such questions

Comment: It helps to understand that *antilog* is just another way of saying *exponent*.

Comment: Greetings and thanks should be left out of questions -- they don't add anything. If someone took the trouble of editing them out of your question, please don't put them back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `pow` method of math.h from C-language.

```
antilog = pow(10, number) ;
```

This will give you antilog of  `number` by `base10`

*Side Note:
As you are creating a Scientific Calculator and you would be needing **Base** for the number.*

EDIT:

```
double number=74.5;
double logOfNumber=log10(number);
double antilog = pow(10, logOfNumber) ;
NSLog(@"%lf",antilog);
```

> Output: 74.500000

[image]

Comment: According to [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log/), `log` computes the **natural logarithm** of the number, so the inverse function would be to raise ***e*** to the exponent, not 10.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006040401576 -> have a look at this...

Comment: I used pow() method few years back, as my final project "Scientific Calculator" while learning Obj-c.

Comment: @lakesh give me a break. Yahoo Answers is **not** a reliable source of information, especially not for programming.

Comment: @lakesh if `pow(10, number)` was the inverse of the `log` function, `printf("%f\n", pow(10, log(17)))` would print `17.000000`. Go ahead, try it. It prints `681.103864`. The whole point of an inverse function is to get the original number back.

Comment: How? this question gave you +15/-4

Comment: thanks alot...its working corectly..

Comment: @SajidKhan: What happend?

Comment: @SajidKhan: I asked you accepted and then rejected. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `exp` function:

```
ans = exp(exponent)
```

Since the [`log` function returns the **natural logarithm** of the number](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log/), you need to use [`exp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/), not [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) to get the inverse, since the `pow` function accepts the base as an argument, and you don't need this since you're taking the natural logarithm of the number, that is, finding *x* in where the number = *e^x*.

Of course, you could always use the [`log10` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/) to get the base 10 logarithm of the number instead, and then you would need to use `pow(10, logarithm)` to get the original value.

#### EDIT to address any confusion:

The **logarithm** of a number can be taken in any base. The `log` function does it in base *e*, that is, it takes the **natural logarithm**, or, it finds *x* where your number = *e^x*. The `log10` function does it in base 10, that is, it finds *x* where your number = *10^x*. If you take the base 10 or other base logarithm of the number, you would use `pow(base, exponent)` to get the original number back, where `base` is the base the logarithm was taken in and `exponent` is the logarithm. However, if you use the `log` function and take the logarithm in base *e*, using `exp(logarithm)` returns the value of *e^logarithm*, and could potentially be more accurate than using `pow(2.7182818285, logarithm)` due to variations in precision.

You just need to make sure you use the right pair of functions to ensure you get the right inverse, i.e.:

```
printf("%f\n", exp(logf(17)));
```

prints 17, while

```
printf("%f\n", pow(10, logf(17)));
```

prints 681.103864, which is clearly not what you want.
You can also use

```
printf("%f\n", pow(10, log10(17)));
```

as these will operate in base 10 and return the correct result due to being in the same base.

Comment: This ***is*** the anti log function. It's just not called "anti log".

Comment: Try this code: `double x = exp(log(17))`. The answer will be 17. Therefore, `exp` is the "anti log" function as it is the exact inverse operation of the `log` function, since it returns the original number when given the output of the `log` function.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite antilog is a less common term for exponentiation -- I wouldn't assume that the operand is base *e* just because the OP said "anti log". Probably best to explicitly state the base. Your explanation above is fine; I'm just pointing out that your assumption may be incorrect.

Comment: @Caleb [the C `log` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log/) *"Returns the **natural logarithm** of x"*, and the OP is using the `log` function.

Comment: @Caleb and by "it's not called anti log" I meant that the C standard library inverse function is not called anti log.

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: @SajidKhan if you are using the `logf` function, you should use the `exp` as your antilog function. If you are using `log10`, you need to use `pow(10, logarithm)`.

Comment: @SajidKhan is this what you're looking for? `secondField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", exp(2.0708)];`

Comment: What "result" do you need? If you set a `double x = 17; double log = log(x); double antilog = exp(log);`, `antilog` will be equal to `x`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Are you sure you know what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   float logOfx(float value, float base) 
   {
        return log10f(value) / log10f(base);
   }
```