# Swift - Find antilog for 4 digit Integer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, darwin

I need to find an antilog for **5995**. I can get the actual antilog value when I am using anti logarithm book. but I could get infinite when I am using below code snippet in iOS. But the correct answer is **3977** How can I calculate the antilog value for 5995 using programatically. Share your valuable suggestions to get the rid of issue.

**LOG**

```
let number = 5995.0
let logOfNumber = log10(number)
print("logOfNumber ", logOfNumber)
```

**ANTI LOG**

```
let antilog = pow(10, number)
print("antilog ", antilog)
```

Although I tried the below link to find it.

[How to find out antilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857749/how-to-find-out-antilog?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the output as `logOfNumber  3.77778918743487
antilog  5995.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value cannot be that much big and it will return you the infinity value.

so say you need to find the antilog for 2.5995. The characteristic is 2, and the mantissa is 5995.

In the example above, you would open the antilog table and find the row number beginning with .59, then the column for 9. In this case, you would find that the corresponding value is 3972

you would again use the row number beginning with .59, but find the column for 5. In this case, your value is 5.

so 3972 + 5 = 3977

the characteristic is 2. You would therefore add 2 and 1 to get 3, then insert the decimal point after 3 digits. The antilog of 2.5995 is therefore 397.7

so to find in your case try let number = 0.5995.